# Toggle comment IJulia notebook on safari

Tags: ijulia-notebook

I am new using IJulia 
I tryed every shortcuts to comment some lines that did not work except pressing alt then clicking at the beginning of the line to insert # that works but which is not ergonomic at all.

I am running IJulia 0.5.1 notebook on safari using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4.
This shortcut obviously must exist somewhere

can someone help please ?

Comment: Isn't it command-/

Comment: yes i saw it also but does not work on mine ..

Comment: do you have other ideas?